# Invalid geometry after polygonizing rasters in R

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-sf

I've a 1 arc-second SRTM raster layer from [USGS](https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov).

I'm trying to turn that raster into a set of polygons for each 100 m elevational bands. I then would like to dissolve or union polygons of same attributes together.

My problem is that the majority of the polygons get an invalid geometry in the process.

I'm not sure where the problem arises so I will describe all the steps I did:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(stars)

# First I open the raster, remove NAs and set the min and max values
r <- raster::raster(my_raster)
raster::NAvalue(r) <- -1
r <- raster::setMinMax(r)

# Then I reclassify the raster in 100 m elevational bands
k <- 100
lv <- raster::minValue(r) %>% floor_nearest(100)
hv <- raster::maxValue(r) %>% floor_nearest(100)
s <- seq(lv, hv, k)

tibble(
  lower = s,
  higher = s + k,
  new = s
) %>% 
  raster::reclassify(r, ., right = FALSE) %>% 

  # Finally, I polygonize the reclassified raster and save the shapefile
  st_as_stars() %>% 
  st_as_sf(as_points = FALSE, merge = TRUE, connect8 = TRUE) %>% 
  st_write(dsn = "my_shapefile.shp")
```

The output of the above code looks like this:
[image]

However, if I check geometry validity in QGis, I end up with just a few valid polygons:
[image]

**Q.** What could be the reason of having so many polygons with an invalid geometry? What solution to fix it?

**EDIT**

Digging a bit more into the problem, I found this useful [resource](https://www.r-spatial.org/r/2017/03/19/invalid.html#corrup-or-invalid-geometries) talking about the issue and different solutions to deal with it.
There is a specific function `st_make_valid` to fix invalid geometries in the `lwgeom` package, which is a dependency of the `sf` package since the version 0.4.

Comment: Noting @Brent-Pease answer, curious where/how polygon validity is checked in QGIS. is is JTE (Java Topology Engine) as in postGIS, and is closing merely that first and last x,y coords  as the same. I think it is a valid question which library or approach is being used to assess polygon validity so one knows, generally, how to heal problematic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are numerous causes of the problem...overlapping geometries, self-intersecting geoms, etc. Try buffering by a distance of 0 - not sure why this works but it’s a common solution on posts like this and it also worked for me when I was in your shoes.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the problem. I also found that there's a specific function accessible from the `sf` package to fix invalid geometries (please see the edit in my post). It produces a slightly different output but might be more appropriate in some cases.